# TCheckListBox Get My Object

Tags: delphi, object, types

i have a problem if i getting my defined type object. 
I need to get my variables-defined object from a ListBox.

My data types:

```
type
  TObjectData = class
    Id: Integer;
    DataType: String;
  end;
  TProjektInfo = record
    Id: Integer;
    Nazev: String;
  end;
  TReportSelect = record
    Count: Integer;
    Zakazka_Id: Integer;
    Singles: Array of TProjektInfo;
    Multies: Array of TProjektInfo;
  end;
```

My procedure for fill listbox:

```
procedure TReportMain.VykresyFillProjectsList();
var
  I,Id: Integer;
  Nazev: String;
  ItemData: TObjectData;
begin
  VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.BeginUpdate;
  VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.Clear;

  for I := Low(ReportSelect.Singles) to High(ReportSelect.Singles) do
  begin

    Id := ReportSelect.Singles[I].Id;
    Nazev := ReportSelect.Singles[I].Nazev;

    ItemData := TObjectData.Create;
    ItemData.Id := Id;
    ItemData.DataType := 'single';

    VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.AddObject(Nazev, TObject(ItemData));
    ItemData.Free;
  end;

  for I := Low(ReportSelect.Multies) to High(ReportSelect.Multies) do
  begin

    Id := ReportSelect.Multies[I].Id;
    Nazev := ReportSelect.Multies[I].Nazev;

    ItemData := TObjectData.Create;
    ItemData.Id := Id;
    ItemData.DataType := 'multi';

    VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.AddObject(Nazev, TObject(ItemData));
    ItemData.Free;
  end;

  VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

My button event on click for getting my datatype object (this is wrong where is commented):

```
procedure TReportMain.BtnExportProjectsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ItemData: TObjectData;
  Nazev: String;
  I: Integer;
begin
  ItemData := TObjectData.Create;

  for I := 0 to VykresyProjectsListSections.Count - 1 do
  begin

    if VykresyProjectsListSections.Checked[I] then
    begin

      ItemData := TObjectData(VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.Objects[I]); // <--- This is wrong, why ?
      Nazev := VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.Strings[I];

      showMessage(Format('Nazev: %s ID: %d Type: %s', [Nazev, ItemData.Id, ItemData.DataType]));

    end;

  end;
end;
```

Comment: You say this is wrong, but not why it is wrong. Please explain. We also don't know what platform you target, and whether or not arc is active.

Comment: Where is the commentary displays Access violation.
Line: ItemData := TObjectData(VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.Objects[I]);
and I do not know why.

Comment: It would help if you supplied the other details that I asked for. And did so in the question **edit** rather than in comments.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner. And my English is not professional.

Comment: OK, that's fine, but you still need to provide that information, and in a question edit

Comment: You are calling `ItemData.Free` after `AddObject()`. This is wrong, since the object will not be valid anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens to you is probably an *access violation*.

The variable you're trying to access is undefined because you have already freed the object the variable is pointing to.

In the code above, the `ItemData` object is always freed after it's added to the list.

You have to write some code to free the object when the list is cleared or freed.

This can be done in the `OnDestroy` event of your form:

```
procedure TReportMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do begin
    VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.Objects[i].Free;
    VykresyProjectsListSections.Delete(i);
  end;

  VykresyProjectsListSections.Free;//free the list if not owned by the application
end;
```

---

As a side note, you can test if a `TCheckListBox` element is checked like this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to VykresyProjectsListSections.Items.Count-1 do begin
    if VykresyProjectsListSections.State[i] = cbChecked then
      //do your stuff
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This, however, does not solve my situation. I need to get the object in the list are checked.

Comment: @LukášVlček This is a question you didn't  ask. The above probably doesn't solve many other situations. At the moment I know not even what kind of component `VykresyProjectsListSections` is. You may consider to edit your question in order to add further details if you want.

Comment: Your answer helped me. I understand that I can not release the object, if I want to work with it. thank you

Comment: And what if ARC is in play?

Comment: @David it should be fine on desktop apps. [ARC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers) *..., the classic try-finally blocks used with the Delphi desktop compilers still work fine under the new compiler, even if they are not required*. Anyway, thank you for pointing me to it because I wasn't aware of ARC on objects since I've never dealt with mobile plat. so far

Comment: My point was rather the other way around. Under ARC, calling `Free` as per the code in the Q won't actually destroy the object because there are other references to it.

Comment: @David so you mean the only way on modern compilers is `nil`ing or `DisposeOf `?

Comment: Under ARC, setting a reference to `nil` is the same as calling `Free`. `DisposeOf` forces the destructor to run.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `ItemData.Free` after `AddObject()`. This is wrong, since the object will not be valid anymore.

This will cause the error when later accessing the object in the `CheckListBox`.

Comment: But not if we are using ARC I guess

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, even if that were the case, it is still not a good practice.

Comment: I don't disagree with that. I just wish that the asker would care about the question a bit more.